# some image show and some image not show (Broken X )

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, yii2, mpdf

some image show and some image not show (Broken X ) code are below there and also  i am using xampp 5 (mpdf)....

```
 if(!empty($row["google_address"])){
            $address =  $row["google_address"].'<br>'.'/'.'Lat - '.$row["latitude"].' / '.'Long - '.$row["longitude"];
            }else{
                $address ='';
            }
                $table .= '<tr>';
                    $table .= "<td>".$i++."</td>";
                    $table .= "<td>".$row["name"]."</td>";
                    $table .= "<td>".$row["mobile"]."</td>";
                    $table .= "<td>".$row["organization_name"]."</td>";
                    $table .= "<td>".$row["beatName"]."</td>";
                    $table .= "<td>".$row["customer_type"]."</td>";
                    $table .= "<td>".$i_Type."</td>";
                    $table .= "<td>".$row["intration_date"]."</td>";
                    $table .= "<td>".$row["next_activity_at"]."</td>";
                    $table .= "<td>".$row["call_time"]."</td>";
                    $table .= "<td>".$row["purpose"]."</td>";
                    $table .= "<td>".$row["status"]."</td>";
                    $table .= "<td>".$vIn."</td>";
                    $table .= "<td>".$vOut."</td>";
                    $table .= "<td>".$row["remark"]."</td>";
                    $table .= "<td>".$row["rating"]."</td>";
                    $table .= "<td>".str_replace('\' ', '\'', ucwords(str_replace('\'', '\' ', strtolower($row["fname"]))))."</td>";
                    $table .= "<td>".$address."</td>";

                    // $pathe = \Yii::getAlias('@web/uploads/crm_images/');
                    // $img = $row["visit_image"] ? ' <img src = "'.$pathe.$row["visit_image"].'" width ="200px" height = "200px">' : '';
                    
                    // $img = $remark1[0]['image_one'] ? ' <img src = "https://timekompas.com/backend/web/uploads/task_photo/'.$remark1[0]['image_one'].'" width ="80px" height = "80px">' : '';
                    $img = $row["visit_image"] ? ' <img src = "https://timekompas.com/backend/web/uploads/crm_images/'.$row["visit_image"].'" width ="200" height = "200">' : '';
                    //echo $row["visit_image"];
                    //echo $img;
                    //die;
                    $table .="<td>".$img."</td>";
```

mpdf code (Xampp 5) :-

```
 $path = \Yii::getAlias("@vendor/MPDF/mpdf.php");
        require_once($path);
        $mpdf = new \mPDF('en-GB-x', 'A4-L', '', '', 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 3);
        // $mpdf->curlAllowUnsafeSslRequests = true;
        // $mpdf->showImageErrors = true;
        // $mpdf->debug = true;
        $mpdf->packTableData = true;
        $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
        $mpdf->SetFooter('Contact no: +91-771-4700067, 7772800067 Email ID: timekompas@entitcs.com');
        $mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0; // 1 or 0 - whether to indent the first level of a list
       // if($_SESSION["isSupAdmin"]=='1')
       // {
      //  $mpdf->SetWatermarkText('TIME KOMPAS');
      //  }
       // else
      //  {
         //   $mpdf->SetWatermarkText('TIME KOMPAS');
         // $mpdf->SetWatermarkText($_SESSION["timecampus_officename"]);
        if($_SESSION["ofc_new_com"] != '' && $_SESSION["ofc_new_name"] != ''){
            
            $mpdf->SetWatermarkText($_SESSION["ofc_new_com"].'( '.$_SESSION["ofc_new_name"].' )');
        }
        if(($_SESSION['order_detail'] != '')||($_SESSION['taskreport_sql'] != '')){
            $employee =\Yii::$app->session->get('empdata');
            $office = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("select ofc_name,company_name from master_office where ofc_id = '".$employee['employee']['emp_ofcid']."' ")->queryOne();
            $mpdf->SetWatermarkText($office["company_name"].'( '.$office["ofc_name"].' )');
        }
     

        //}
        /* $table .=$_SESSION['khumesh_map']; */
        //$mpdf->SetWatermarkText($_SESSION['ofc_new_com']);
      
        $mpdf->showWatermarkText = true;
        $mpdf->watermarkTextAlpha = 0.3;
        $mpdf->simpleTables = true;
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($table);
        $mpdf->Output($filename . '.pdf', 'I');
        
        exit;
```

problem image (in my image one image show and one image show x and 2 image is blank because of that empty. )

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lbd25.png)

how can i solve that problem to solve my problem

Comment: I don't see why you include the 2nd code example. Please include less code or just the specific line.

Comment: 2nd code in my pdf download code in 1st code for image and if i print image than its see but download in pdf then its see like broken x that's way i add both code

Answer (score 0):

that code is fine there are image size issue ,image size above than 20 kb that's a reason

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).